# Xamarin forms animate increase/decrease in numeric value as label text

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Label whose Text property is a numeric value. When that number changes, I'd like to animate the change in number. So for example if the Text is set to 100 and changes to 120 I'd like to show it increment from 100 to 101 to 102 etc. every few milliseconds until it reaches the new value of 120.

I can do this in code behind manually, but since I'm using MVVM I'd like to find a way to do it in the XAML (e.g. behavior, effect, etc.). I'm sure I could also do it by using a custom renderer, but it feels like there should be a simpler way to do this that I'm unaware of. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have working code in case it helps anyone else. Someone will hopefully post a better answer, but this at least works for me for now.

I created a Behavior that watches for the PropertyChanged event on the Label. When the Text property changes, I parse the new value of the label into a long and compare it to the previous value of the label. If there is a difference between the two I step the value up one at a time with an await Task.Delay(300) in between to slow the count down. I used a static dictionary to track the previous value. Working code below - although still testing...

```
public class LabelHighlightAndStepOnChangeBehavior : Behavior<Label>
{
    public int EndHighlightDuration { get; set; } = 3000;

    public string Property { get; set; }

    public static Dictionary<string, long> _previousValues = new Dictionary<string, long>();

    private bool _watchingTextChanges = true;

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Label element)
    {
        try
        {
            element.PropertyChanged += Label_PropertyChanged;
            base.OnAttachedTo(element);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(ex, false);
        }
    }

    private async void Label_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_watchingTextChanges && e.PropertyName == nameof(Label.Text))
            {
                _watchingTextChanges = false;
                var label = (Label)sender;
                var model = label.BindingContext as BaseModel;
                var key = model.Id + Property;

                if (_previousValues.ContainsKey(key) && _previousValues[key] != model.GetPropertyValue<long>(Property))
                {
                    // Change background color.
                    var originalBackgroundColor = label.BackgroundColor;
                    label.BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow;

                    // Step the number up or down to the new value.
                    var originalValue = _previousValues[key];
                    var newValue = model.GetPropertyValue<long>(Property);
                    _previousValues[key] = newValue;

                    if (originalValue < newValue)
                    {
                        var step = Math.Max(1, Convert.ToInt32((newValue - originalValue) / 50.0) - 1);
                        while (originalValue < newValue)
                        {
                            if ((originalValue + step) <= newValue)
                                originalValue += step;
                            else
                                originalValue = newValue;

                            model.SetPropertyValue<long>(Property, originalValue);
                            await Task.Delay(50);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (originalValue > newValue)
                    {
                        var step = -Math.Max(1, Convert.ToInt32((originalValue - newValue) / 50.0) - 1);
                        while (originalValue > newValue)
                        {
                            if ((originalValue + step) <= newValue)
                                originalValue += step;
                            else
                                originalValue = newValue;

                            model.SetPropertyValue<long>(Property, originalValue);
                            await Task.Delay(50);
                        }
                    }

                    // Change the background color back.
                    await Task.Delay(EndHighlightDuration);
                    label.BackgroundColor = originalBackgroundColor;
                }
                else if (!_previousValues.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    _previousValues.Add(key, model.GetPropertyValue<long>(Property));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(ex, false);
        }
        finally
        {
            _watchingTextChanges = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Label element)
    {
        try
        {
            element.PropertyChanged -= Label_PropertyChanged;
            base.OnDetachingFrom(element);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(ex, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Animation class to change a number between a start and end value, using an Easing function to specify how the number change happens, and a duration over which it happens.

You can then bind your label to e.g. an "Amount" property, set a _targetAmount, and then animate "Amount" between the current amount and the _targetAmount, using your desired animation properties. The label will update accordingly via the binding.

In order to animate a property on a view model, you must first mark the view model class as IAnimatable. Then simply set _targetAmount and call AnimateAmountChange() to update the label in an animated stylee.

```
    private void AnimateAmountChange()
    {
        var change = new Animation(x => Amount = (int)x, Amount, _targetAmount);
        change.Commit(this, "ChangeAmount", 10, 300, Easing.SinOut);
    }

    #region IAnimatable
    public void BatchBegin()
    {
    }

    public void BatchCommit()
    {
    }
    #endregion
```